# A construction of $\mathfrak{e}_8$ in Fulton and Harris

Tags: abstract-algebra, representation-theory, lie-algebras, root-systems, dynkin-diagrams

In section $22.4$ of "Representation Theory: A First Course" by Fulton and Harris, the exceptional Lie algebra $\mathfrak{e}_8$ is constructed using a method of Freudenthal.  For background, I will briefly describe the construction.  Let $\mathfrak{g}_0:=\mathfrak{sl}_9$ and let $V$ be the standard $9$-dimensional representation of $\mathfrak{g}_0$.  Let $W=\bigwedge^3V$ and consider the vector space

$$\mathfrak{g}=\mathfrak{g}_0\oplus W\oplus W^*$$

The bracket on $\mathfrak{g}$ is then defined using the action of $\mathfrak{g}_0$ on $W$ and $W^*$, the trilinear maps $W^{\otimes 3}\to\mathbb{C}$ and $(W^*)^{\otimes 3}\to\mathbb{C}$ given by the wedge product, and the Killing form on $\mathfrak{g}_0$.

My question concerns part of exercise $22.21$, which is to verify that the Dynkin diagram of $\mathfrak{g}$ is $E_8$.  Another result in the same section says that the Cartan subalgebra of $\mathfrak{g}$ is the same as that of $\mathfrak{g}_0$.  Hence we may choose the simple roots of $\mathfrak{g}$ to be

$$\{(L_i-L_{i+1},0,0)\mid i=1,2,\ldots,8\}$$

where $L_i(A)=A_{ii}$ for any traceless diagonal matrix $A$.  How do I show that these roots give the Dynkin diagram $E_8$?  In order to use these roots to construct the Dynkin diagram for $\mathfrak{g}$, I know that I need to be able to compute the Killing form ($\alpha,\beta$) for two simple roots $\alpha$ and $\beta$, but I don't know how to do this.

Comment: What you've written down isn't a set of simple roots for e8.  They are all zero on $W$ and $W^*$!  The root space decomposition wrt your CSA consists of the sl9 roots together with the weights for the action of the CSA on $W$ and $W^*$.  You've got to study these to find a set of simple roots.

Comment: @mt_:  Thanks for the reply.  I don't exactly see why these are not simple roots, can you explain a bit more?  If they are not simple, then I'm confused by Fulton and Harris saying that the Cartan subalgebra of $\mathfrak{g}$ is the same as that of $\mathfrak{g}_0$ (Proposition $22.19$).

Comment: What you have can't be the set of simple roots: if it was, any root would vanish on $W$ (since any root is a linear combination of simple roots).  So the CSA, which *is* what you say it is, would act trivially on $W$ -- but it doesn't.  To find a set of simple roots, you must first "know" all roots.  Otherwise how could you show that any root is a positive or negative linear combination of your putative root system?